# Use a script within a For Loop in batch

Tags: batch-file

Is there a way within Batch that I can use a Visual Basic Script in place of the file/string field? Specifically I'm attempting to get something like the below to work so I can automatically store the printer drivers for a given printer as a variable to be used later on in a script so that I can sanitize the printer completely when uninstalling it.

```
For /f "delims=" %%a in ('cscript prnmngr.vbs -l|findstr -i /c:"driver name"') do for /f "delims=" %%b in ("%%a") do set "driverName=%%a"
```

Ideally it should take the print out from cscript prnmngr.vbs -l|findstr -i /c:"driver name", select the first driver that comes up and then stores that as a variable named driverName I can use later.

Unfortunately I'm deploying the script over limited environment so Powershell is not an option.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the 2nd `FOR /F` loop. It appears to have no logical effect (except for possibly trimming a single trailing carriage return of the end of the value, which is rarely an issue, and I seriously doubt is your intent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A problem with the command you've posted is that the pipe `|` needs to be escaped `^|` within the parentheses.

Beyond that, I'm having difficulty discerning what you are enquiring about.

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much Mr. Magoo